# Database for managing large volumes of (system) metrics

Tags: database, performance, monitor, olap, time-series

I'm looking at building a system for managing and reporting stats on web page performance. I'll be collecting a lot more stats than are available in the standard log formats (approx 20 metrics) but compared to most types of database applications, the base data structure will be very simple. My problem is that I'll be accumulating a lot of data - in the region of 100,000 records (i.e. sets of metrics) per hour.

Of course, resources are very limited!

So that its possible to sensibly interact with the data, I'd need to consolidate each metric into one minute bins, broken down by URL, then for anything more than 1 day old, consolidated into 10 minute bins, then at 1 week, hourly bins.

At the front end, I want to provide a view (prefereably as plots) of the last hour of data, with the facility for users to drill up/down through defined hierarchies of URLs (which do not always map directly to the hierarchy expressed in the path of the URL) and to view different time frames.

Rather than coding all this myself and using a relational database, I was wondering if there were tools available which would facilitate both the management of the data and the reporting.

I had a look at [Mondrian](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/) however I can't see from the documentation I've looked at whether it's possible to drop the more granular information while maintaining the consolidated views of the data.

[RRDTool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/index.en.html) looks promising in terms of managing the data consolidation, but seems to be rather limited in terms of querying the dataset as a multi-dimensional/relational database.

What else whould I be looking at?

Comment: It seems I'm not the only one looking at this stuff - http://www.springerlink.com/content/p322w81715p8432l/abstract/ - unfortunately they don't seem to have turned this into a useable bit of software

Comment: Check my math. You're looking at 2.4 million rows/day, and 876 million rows/year. For 20 metrics, estimate about 90 bytes a row, you get about 80 gigs a year. Is that right?

Comment: And, does "whether it's possible to drop the more granular information while maintaining the consolidated views of the data" mean you plan to do some aggregation on the 100K rows/hour, store the aggregates, and throw away the original rows? (Or, if not throw away, at least delete them from the data warehouse?)

Comment: @Catcall: yes, I can only sensibly store an hours worth of data at the most granular level - I need to keep the summarized data for longer periods (period depending on level of consolidation)

Comment: Did you consider free or contract web analytics? Google Analytics is free for me, but probably isn't free for 2.4 million hits per day.

Comment: @Catcall: yes - but there are a lot of metrics I'm trying to capture which are not available in GA - and using GA brings a lot of client load for measuring stuff I'm not interested in - there are also other considerations at play here which mean GA is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still failed to find anything suitable :(

While I can sink data at this rate in MySQL, it starts to get a bit lumpy when I'm trying to consolidate it / remove old low level data. So I guess I'm going to have to look at building the aggregation layer on top of the DBMS and switch to a noSQL system - and write it all myself :(

Answer (score 1):

Your above answer mentioning [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/) is a great solution if you're up for managing the Graphite instance (and likely you'd also be using [Statsd](https://github.com/etsy/statsd)) yourself. Alternatively, there are a lot of other hosted apps out there that are beginning to offer this sort of functionality. There's [StatHat](http://www.stathat.com/), [Librato Metrics](https://metrics.librato.com/), and my own company's product, [Instrumental](http://instrumentalapp.com/). It can definitely handle the metric load you're asking for at our lowest plan - we've got an [official client (Ruby)](https://github.com/fastestforward/instrumental_agent/), a [Statsd-compatible proxy](https://github.com/fastestforward/statsd-instrumental), and a documented way to post to our collector yourself, as well as a nice way to pull your metrics back out via our API in case you'd like to build your own presentation layer beyond our graphs.

Answer (score 0):

In [icCube](http://www.icCube.com) it's pretty straightforward to get a time dimension with different granularity over the time (for an example of "range/banded" dimension, you can have a look [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/dim_ranged.html)). Then cubes can be built from CSV files. Its XMLA interface allows you then to use any XMLA compliant reporting tool. Do you have an estimate of how large would be your typical datasets?

Comment: Looks interesting - but that's a company which really needs to spend some time looking at web performance!

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean?

Comment: it took nearly 15 seconds to load the first page of their website (I've got a reasonably fast internet connection) - I thought that rather ironic since I'm looking at measuring website performance!

Comment: Understood - I guess a transient issue with the hosting; I do not see such issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use an industry-standard database.. Like SQL Server.. with Analysis Services on top (if you start getting millions of rows)

Comment: Aaron, what do you mean with "millions"? As an example, I've played around with a cube of almost 100 millions of rows with less than 4GB of RAM in icCube (without any compression activated).

Answer (score 0):

Mondrian requires you to provide your own dbms; Mondrian plus PostgreSQL might be worth trying. With your own dbms, of course, you can delete whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

This Q&A rather old, but I've recently found something which looks like it matches my requirements - [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/start). Still to get an installation up and running - but it looks very promising.

Answer (score 0):

Try using InfluxDB (http://influxdb.com/) an open-source distributed time series database.

It has a restful interface for posting metrics like

```
[
  {
    "name" : "hd_used",
    "columns" : ["value", "host", "mount"],
    "points" : [
      [23.2, "serverA", "/mnt"]
    ]
  }
]
```

You can easily visualize your metrics using the Grafana (http://grafana.org/)